# Can I exclude a single URL from a rewrite plugin?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

I am working on an imported .html site that has been using the [.html on pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-on-pages/) plugin to rewrite the URLs for inbound link purposes.  Now I am trying to integrate it with a subdomain blog (domain.com/blog/) that also needs to maintain inbound links.

Everything is setup and working correctly except the blog archive page.  The permalinks are set to (/blog/%postname%/) and the URLs are correct for both pages and posts. The only issue is the page set to frontpage (/blog/)is being rewritten to /blog.html/ so links to (domain.com/blog/) are getting a 404.

There doesn't seem to be an easy way to exclude the page from the .html rewrite.  I tried using a conditional tag, but the plugin hooks to 'init' so it doesn't work. Is there another way to exclude that page from being rewritten?  Or is there some other (hopefully simpler) way to achieve a blog archive at (domain.com/blog/)?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly solve your problem but you could [redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) from /blog.html to /blog